# Way to count a php array with key separation

Tags: php, arrays, sum, keyword

I could need some help from the experts here :)

I do have an php array:

```
Array ( [A] => 5 [B] => 1 [A,B] => 5 )
```

For statistics i need to summ the value for each keyword. So I would need an output like this:

```
Array ( [A] => 10 [B] => 6 )
```

Someone an idea? Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$arr = [ 'A' => 5, 'B' => 1, 'A,B' => 5 ];

$result = [];

array_walk($arr, function ($value, $key) use (&$result) {
  $keys = explode(',', $key);
  foreach ($keys as $key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $result)) {
      $result[$key] += $value;
    } else {
      $result[$key] = $value;
    }
  }
});

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [A] => 10
    [B] => 6
)
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation of the posed code, or it won't be very helpful for others with similar, but not identical, issues/questions.

Comment: Hey Lukas.j,

many many thanks! The code is working and I will lookup the functions myself to have a learning effect. You saved my day! 

Kind regards